# Confused about which docker driver running which iso

Tags: docker, openstack, docker-machine, rancher

I am running docker v. 1.27 and will be deploying a machine (v.0.10) on an OpenStack layer.  I am trying to decide if I should use a *virtualbox* or *openstack* driver with a rancheros iso.  I am new to using any type of Docker "technology".  From what I understand, if I use an *openstack* driver, my machines will be able to make use of the OpenStack features but from what I read there has been a lot of flux with the drivers (Nova) and I can't seem to find any drivers anywhere.  Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Since docker never released a 1.27 release, and don't know what the v0.10 machine refers to, I'm rather confused by what you're running and what your question is.

Comment: I guess that's API Version.  Version is 17.04 and machine refers to `docker-machine` version.  I guess what I'm asking is what exactly is the _openstack_ driver and what benefit does it provide?  Which now that I put it that way, this is probably not the forum for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of the Docker Machine drivers: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/
Basically it's up to you and what's installed on the host you're connecting to. As I understand it you're connecting to OpenStack so it seems natural you would want to use an openstack driver, but it depends on your configuration. For instance, if I use Docker Machine locally on my Mac, I use the virtualbox driver. But on my PC, I use hyperv.